# powershell remove software from PC

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $PCNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$softwareName" }).Uninstall() | Out-Null
```

I have following code which works perfectly. The only problem is that I wont to know if the software has been removed or not.This doesn't tells me but the code below does.

This way works for me.

```
$software = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $PCNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$softwareName" }

$soft = $software.Uninstall();
$n = $software.ReturnValue;

if ( $n -eq 0 ){
SOFTWARE HAS BEEN REMOVED.
}
```

my question is that how do i tell if the software has been removed or not.
using this code.

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $PCNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$softwareName" }).Uninstall() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the ReturnValue property. When you pipe to `Out-Null` you are suppressing the output of the operation and there's no way to tell what happened, unless you issue a second call to find if it returns the software in question.

I recommend using the Filter parameter (instead of using `Where-Object`) to query the software on the server. To be safe you should also pipe the results to the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet, you never know how many software objects you get back due to the match operation (and you call the Uninstall method as if the result is one object only):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $PCNumber -Filter "Name LIKE '%$softwareName%'" | Foreach-Object { 

     Write-Host "Uninstalling: $($_.Name)"

     $rv = $_.Uninstall().ReturnValue 

     if($rv -eq 0)
     {
        "$($_.Name) uninstalled successfully"
     }     # Changed this round bracket to a squigly one to prperly close the scriptblock for "if"
     else
     {
        "There was an error ($rv) uninstalling $($_.Name)"
     }
}
```

Comment: I have few programs which i need to remove and i need wait for one to finish first thats why i was using out-null. out-null waits for first program to finish.

Comment: Thats why i need to make sure script waits for first program to run before excuting second one.

Comment: You can try and assign the output to a variable instead of using Out-Null.

Comment: Can we still uninstall large application like Microsoft Office with Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product method?